# How to highlight entire row if any cell is empty in html table

Tags: java, html

I have created html table in mail body using below code

```
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT nvl(tt.ACTIVITY_NAME,'') as ACTIVITY_NAME, "
                    + " nvl(tt.TL_NAME,'') TL_NAME, "
                    + " nvl(tt.UW_NAME,'') UW_NAME, "
                    + " nvl(tt.TAT_1,'') TAT_1,"
                    + " nvl(tt.TAT_2,'') TAT_2, "
                    + " nvl(tt.TAT_3,'') TAT_3, "
                    + " nvl(tt.TAT_4,'') TAT_4, "
                    + " nvl(tt.TAT_4_PLUS ,'') TAT_4_PLUS, "
                    + " nvl(tt.g_total ,'') AS GRAND_TOTAL "
                    + " FROM uw_activity_tl_uw_tat tt "
                    + " WHERE tt.ACTIVITY_NAME = 'First UW' "
                    + " ORDER BY tt.TL_NAME,tt.UW_NAME");
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                sb.append("<th bgcolor=#fcbe07>" + columnName + "</th>");
            }
            ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {

                a.add(rs.getString(3));

                if (rs.getRow() % 2 == 0) {
                    sb.append("<tr bgcolor=#fcf6cf>");
                    for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
                        if (rs.getString(i) == null) {
                            if(i==3)
                            {
                                sb.append("<td bgcolor=#fcbe07><b>"+ " "+ "</b></td>");

                            }


                        } else {

                            if (i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8)
                                sb.append("<td><FONT COLOR=#ff0000>"
                                        + rs.getString(i) + "</FONT></td>");
                            else if(i==3 && (rs.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase("") || rs.getString(3)==null)){
                                sb.append("<td bgcolor=#fcbe07><b>"+ rs.getString(i) + "</b></td>");
                            }else{
                                sb.append("<td>" + rs.getString(i) + "</td>");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    sb.append("</tr>");
                } else {

                    sb.append("<tr>");
                    for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
                        if (rs.getString(i) == null) {
                            if(i==3)
                            {
                                sb.append("<td bgcolor=#fcbe07><b>"+ " " + "</b></td>");

                            }

                        } else {
                            if (i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8)
                                sb.append("<td><FONT COLOR=#ff0000>"
                                        + rs.getString(i) + "</FONT></td>");
                            else if(i==3 && (rs.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase("") || rs.getString(3)==null)){
                                sb.append("<td bgcolor=#fcbe07><b>"+ rs.getString(i) + "</b></td>");
                            }else{
                                sb.append("<td>" + rs.getString(i) + "</td>");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    sb.append("</tr>");

                }

            }

            String html = "<html>" + message.getSubject()
                    + "</title></head><body><table border=\"1\">"
                    + sb.toString() + "</table></body></html>";
            message.setContent(html, "text/html");
```

In the image only one cell is highlighted and I want to highlight the entire row which has any empty cell.Please guide. My query is how to highlight the entire row if any cell is empty.

Comment: are you learning this stuff ?

Comment: just consider the suggestions made to improve your code, in the answers. don't be seduced by the lure of bad code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Move the check for the third column and change the `<tr>` line.

Truthfully, the code you have is a bit of a mess.  Personally, I would make the following changes that will make maintence *so* much easier:

1. Switch to using classes instead of hard coding bgcolors and so forth.
2. Set up your system to return associative arrays instead of numeric arrays.  That will make reading the code after a lot easier.
3. Set up intermediate variables to hold the values returned.  Do any and all of your calculations and settings things there.  THEN dump the entire table-row in one go.  That separates your "functional" code from your "display code."

However, in a pinch, something like this will get you going:

```
tmp = rs.getString(3);
if (tmp == null) {
  sb.append("<tr bgcolor=#ffffff>");
} else {
  sb.append("<tr bgcolor=#fcf6cf>");
}
```

BTW - the HTML you generate isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head

```
boolean cellNull = false;
while(rs.next()){
    cellNull = false;
    cellNull = checkIfAnyFieldIsNull(rs);
    if(cellNull)
        sb.append("<tr bgcolor=\"#WTH\">");
    else
        sb.append("<tr>");

    //create rest of the row content here
}


private boolean checkIfAnyFieldIsNull(ResultSet rs){
    for(i=0 etc..){
        if(rs.getString(i) == null)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be as follows:

- Create a [`POJO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class with all the columns that you want to display. Also have a *boolean* variable, say *empty*. Set it to true, if any of your column is *null*
- Create a ArrayList and add each instance of your class as you iterate through your *resultset*
- Now use this *ArrayList* to render your output. Since you already have the boolean variable availabe, you can use this value to set the background color of your row.